# Gradual Migration from DB2 to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I have been working on a project where I have a DB2 Database System.
This system is gonna be not used anymore on behalf of Hadoop.

The source of the system are EBCDIC.

At first I thought to use tools such as SQOOP to clone the old dataBase.
Because I have the data file and the file where are written the SQL code to create the tables and I have not access to DB2 Database, I cannot use SQOOP, can I ?

Are there different ways to operate?

Comment: What does the data look like?  Since you say it's EBCDIC I'm guessing you're running DB2/400, so it's possible it's just a fixed width or delimited file.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I will add further information tomorrow. At the moment I have not those information